# Tree traversal inorder tail recursion

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

Did I implement inorder level-order tree transversal using tail-recursion correctly?

```
inorder (Leaf n) temp = n:temp
inorder (Node (n, left, right)) temp = inorder left (n:inorder right temp)
inorder :: Tree a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Tree is declared as

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (a, Tree a, Tree a) deriving Show
```

and returns
`[2,1,3]` on call `inorder three []` where `three = Node (1, Leaf 2, Leaf 3)`

Comment: I think you indeed did it the correct way. Only point of comment is that you place the type signature below the implementation. This is not wrong, but a bit weird.

Comment: Side note: why not simply `Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`? Using a triple as you do adds one unnecessary level of indirection...

Comment: the implementation will produce what you expect but it's not tail-recursive (the second call to `inorder` for the right subtree is not in tail-call position) - but in Haskell we don't care about TCO here as this will produce a lazy-structure (the list) anway - indeed a simple `inorder left ++ [n] ++ inorder righ` might be more idiomatic

Comment: @Carsten, that simple version runs into painful left-stacked list concatenation.

Comment: @dfeuer true of course - the question is if this really is important at this point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This technically isn't tail recursive because you have a recursive call `inorder right temp` in a nontail position. One way to fix this would be with continuations. You write a function which takes an accumulator like before, but rather than the accumulator being just a list it's actually a function representing the work left to do in the computation. This means that instead of making a non-tail call and just returning, we can always tail call because the context we need is saved to the continuation.

```
  inorder = go id
    where go :: ([a] -> r) -> Tree a -> r
          go k Leaf = k []
          go k (Node a l r) = go l (\ls -> go r (\rs -> k $ ls ++ n : rs))
```

Here every call is a tail call as required but it's quite innefficient because it requires a `++` operation at every level, pushing us into quadratic costs. A more efficient algorithm would avoid building up an explicit list and instead build up a difference list, delaying the construction on the concrete structure and giving a more efficient algorithm

```
type Diff a = [a] -> [a] -- A difference list is just a function

nil :: Diff a
nil xs = xs

cons :: a -> Diff a -> Diff a
cons a d = (:) a . d

append :: Diff a -> Diff a -> Diff a
append xs ys = xs . ys

toList :: Diff a -> a
toList xs = xs []
```

Note that all of these operations are `O(1)` except for `toList` which is `O(n)` in the number of entries. The important point here is that diff lists are cheap and easy to append so we'll construct these in our algorithm and construct the concrete list at the very end

```
 inorder = go toList
    where go :: (Diff a -> r) -> Tree a -> r
          go k Leaf = k nil
          go k (Node a l r) = 
             go l (\ls -> go r (\rs -> k $ ls `append` cons n rs))
```

And now, through gratuitous application of functions we've gotten a completely unidiomatic Haskell program. You see in Haskell we don't really care about tail calls because we generally want to handle infinite structures correctly and that's not really possible if we demand everything be tail recursive. In fact, I would say that while not tail recursive, the code you originally had is the most idiomatic, that's even how it's implemented in `Data.Set`! It has the property that we can lazily consume the result of that `toList` and it will work with us and lazily process the tree. So in your implementation, something like

```
min :: Tree a -> a
min = listToMaybe . toList
```

is going to be pretty darn close to how you would implement it by hand efficiency wise! It will not construct traverse the whole tree first like my version will have to. These sort of compositional effects of laziness pay more dividends in real Haskell code than syntactically making our code use only tail calls (which does nothing to actually guarantee space usage anyways).

Comment: That bit about compiling calls to `jmp` is a bit fishy. Thunks *can* stack up, causing trouble. This just isn't a problem in many cases Scheme or ML programmers might imagine.

Comment: @dfeuer I think it's oversimplifying too so I've removed it. But it's also not necessarily a problem that can be solved by putting something in tail recursive form though is it? After all, the code I wrote is essentially what you'd get with a CPS transformation which is not so dis-similar to what you'd get with STG, some of these things just allocate context and with Haskell we don't allocate that context in the place pointed to by `%esp` unlike C basically. Seem fairer?

Comment: I don't know any of the assembly details, unfortunately. I fully agree that blindly making everything tail recursive is the wrong way to go! I try to think in terms of how computations stack up behind constructors, or, more heuristically, try to make small things strict and tail recursive and try to make large things lazy and incremental.

Comment: Very instructive, thank you!